# Getting MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED Error on new Mongosh version

Tags: mongodb, installation

[image: Error message]

Hello!

as you can see it on the picture above, typing mongosh to the cmd line will not start the mongodb for some reason. I have tried some solutions on the stackoverflow or youtube but none of them worked for me. On my udemy course, instructor just opens the cmd line and types mongosh and it starts working after the installation. I have checked many times any there are no issues with the installation. I would be happy if you could help me out.

Comment: You need to have a `mongod` instance (MongoDB database server) running to connect to the database with/using `mongosh` .

Comment: what do you mean by that? if you mean running mongod command, that does not work on the latest version anymore.

Comment: After installing MongoDB you can start it as a Windows service _or_ start manually. Refer this: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/